# WordPress database plugin for own data

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins

I'm looking for a WordPress plugin to manage and store data (preferably in a separate database, or at least a separate table from the rest of WordPress ).  Something along the lines of [Caspio Bridge](http://www.caspio.com) or [Zoho Creator](https://www.zoho.com/creator/), but much simpler.  I don't need to be able to do much with it (at the moment) - just import/export csv and search through it.

Whenever I try and search for anything to do with databases and WordPress all I get is information on it's database, so hoping someone here will have some suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:
Creating Tables with Plugins
http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Answer (score -1):

There is PHPMyadmin plugn for Wordpress here:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-phpmyadmin/

And the small Adminer plugin too:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminer/

Comment: the first link is broken. i would like to get my hands though on phpmyadmin from the wp dashboard

Comment: As of 2019, both plugins are discontinued.